# Componentes dinámicos en REACT

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal, componentes, ui

**Hola**

he creado un componente modal en react, ademas
he creado varios formularios en componente como registro de usuarios, crear tareas, crear citas, 
aún no he logrado como enviar esos componentes dinamicamente al modal y renderizarlo en su contenido. 
Me gustaria recibir alguna sugerencia o pista

Comment: agrega tu código, lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example